# remove a pv from lvm

Tags: filesystems, lvm

i have 2 disks (4T & 2T) as lvm formatted as ext4... i've only used around 1T and wish to remove the 2T disk. is this possible? i've tried running:

```
pvmove /dev/sdb1
```

but errors `No extents available for allocation`

Edit: more info

`pvs`:

```
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sdb1  vgmain lvm2 a--  <1.82t    0 
  /dev/sdc1  vgmain lvm2 a--  <3.64t    0
```

`vgs`:

```
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  vgmain   2   1   0 wz--n- <5.46t    0
```

Comment: perhaps you want `pvremove` - since you *wish to **remove** the 2T disk* - perhaps `vgreduce` to remove a physical volume from a volume group may also be needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `umount` the filesystem
2. Reduce the size of the filesystem by at least the size of the PV you want to remove (with e.g. `resize2fs` or `fsadm`; this step can be integrated into the next one with `lvresize --resizefs`)
3. Reduce the size of the LV by at least the size of the PV you want to remove (`lvresize`); check the success with `pvs` and `vgs`.
4. Use `pvmove` for moving all the data to other PVs.
5. Use `vgreduce` for taking a disk out of a VG.
6. Use `pvremove` for making the disk not look like a PV any more.

In order for `pvmove` to work there must be enough free space on the other PVs (see `pvs`).

Comment: i've only used 1T out of the ~6T storage, but both my disks says 0 free for `pvs`. i guess in this case i got to go the caveman route and backup data and recreate the storage as i wish...

Comment: @AntonA That will not be necessary. Add the outputs of `pvs` and `vgs` to your question.

Comment: thanks a lot for your attention, i have added the info...

Comment: @AntonA, note that amount of space used or free in the _filesystem_ is not the same as the amount of space used of free in the _volume group_. LVM doesn't know about things like "files" or "ext4", it just allocates space for volumes and makes them available a bit like disk partitions. If you have a 6 TB logical volume on a 6 TB volume group, the VG is full, regardless of what you've stored in the LV. (or even if the LV is totally cleared!) If it just so happens that you have a single filesystem spanning the whole VG, you'll need to look into resizing the filesystem first.

Comment: (resizing the filesystem, and then resizing the LV, and then possibly moving the LV completely to the other PV, and then you get to remove the PV from the VG.)

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks for the pointer about filesystem resizing

Comment: @ilkkachu voila! it worked... thanks much!!